# ZUUIRevealViewController passing values between rear and front view controllers

Tags: iphone

I am using `ZUUIRevealViewController`. I have got one `UITableview` each in the frontview controller and the rearviewcontroller.Depending on the values passed, I have to dynamically reload the `UITableview` in both controllers. How can I pass values to and fro from frontview controller to rearview controller and vice versa?
The code that I am using for navigating is

```
[(ZUUIRevealController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController revealToggle:nil];
```

and  for going back

```
 RevealController *revealController = [self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[RevealController class]] ? (RevealController *)self.parentViewController : nil;
[revealController revealToggle:self];
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can pass parameters while calling revealToggle method?